# LetterCharacter for Cyrillic symbols

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

Why does the code

```
StringMatchQ["ы", LetterCharacter]
```

return `False`?

Probably because:

```
StringMatchQ["ы", LetterCharacter] // HoldForm // FullForm
(*HoldForm[StringMatchQ["\:044b",LetterCharacter]]*)
```

How can I use the `LetterCharacter` pattern with Cyrillic symbols?

Comment: I have notified WRI about this problem in August. But this problem still persists in 10.0.2. Also there are problems with ToUpperCase, ToLowerCase and other functions that use option IgnoreCase (LongestCommonSequence, SequenceAlignment). Sort in some cases also didn't work with russian letters correctly.

Comment: Hi ! Although informative this does not answer the question at hand. It is better suited as a comment and also contains a mistake. The so called Cyrillic letters are not Russian :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code

```
StringMatchQ["ы", LetterCharacter]
```

returns `False`, because only the following characters are treated as letters:

```
StringJoin[Select[Characters[FromCharacterCode[Range[2^16 - 1]]], LetterQ]]
```

> [image: letters]

and `LetterCharacter` only matches the characters for which `LetterQ` gives `True`.
You can include Cyrillic symbols using:

```
StringMatchQ["ы", LetterCharacter | RegularExpression["[А-я]"]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Or define your own

```
letterCharacter = LetterCharacter | RegularExpression["[А-я]"]

StringMatchQ["ы", letterCharacter]
```

> ```
> True
> ```